# Should we use CSS in Karma Unit level tests in AngularJS projects

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Say your Javascript performs some element/position calculations e.g. in angularjs directive.

In order to test this Javascript code is it appropriate to include CSS in karma.conf.js ?

I see that some popular projects did include css files.

e.g. `ng-grid`project [karma.conf.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/test/karma.conf.js)

> ```
> 'dist/release/ui-grid.css',
> ```

The questions is more towards the boundary of e2e tests vs. unit tests.

Comment: I don't really understand what you would need the CSS for

Comment: @StephanMuller Many times Directives use HTML template?Url. When you have HTML you will have CSS. Post linking functions may need to calculate positions e.g. tool tip placement using read only offsetLeft properties which are defined if the CSS loaded properly. Without this the calculation logic (beyond addition/subtraction) cannot be tested because offsetLeft is not reliable.

Comment: I think the answer should be yes. If you are using element dimensions or coordinates in directives and want to test them then it could make sense to use the real css file instead of setting inline within the test, perhaps could be considered an integration test though, inline css maybe preferred for pure unit test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, here's my take on this -

*Unit test are to check functionality of particular source code.*

There are following ways to do unit testing for a function

1. Pass the input to function and test the output
2. Pass the input and test every thing (steps) it does to manipulate that input
3. Test if its calling anything external function to get any input & use the stubbed value as a returned object/value from that external function

If a method in directive is manipulating css, then it should be adding and removing CSS class inside that method, isn't it? So in assertions it need to check only if particular class is present or not. (In most of the cases which I worked on)

CSS file is external file and its a dependancy for javascript source file & it should be treated as dependancies.

Where as e2e testing is the like integration testing, to make sure if all integration files work together perfectly. So if we need to test CSS changes, we should check with e2e.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w) is interesting talk on Unit Testing from Miško Hevery. It's not related to CSS, but in general Unit Testing & about handling dependancies(17:50)

Comment: It is not able adding or removing CSS. Directives load template HTML which may have CSS and postLink functions may need to position the elements properly.